# Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to connect MySQL client through a Perl script. But again and again I am getting error

> ERROR 1251: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

My MySQL client has been upgraded from 5.1 to 5.6.

I am using Perl v5.12.0, `DBD::mysql` is 4.017, `DBI` is 1.613.

Is this problem with the Perl module or with MySQL.

Comment: DBD::mysql doesn't use the CLI, it uses the C API, so upgrading the client won't affect your Perl code. Try upgrading DBD::mysql.

Comment: Do I need to upgrade DBD::mysql to latest version?

Answer (score 0):

in my.conf
add

[mysqld]
skip-secure-auth=true

it permiss use old protocol, but your security exists no more. Do it only in development ambient.